# C# application on a NUC computer (Windows 10) for data collection over long period of time

Tags: c#, windows-10

I'm working on a project that involves grabbing frames from several cameras, all connected by USB to an Intel NUC computer running Windows 10.

I want to write C# application(s?) for that end.
The scenario is as followed:

- Every hour, I need to grab several frames (1-5) from each camera. Then go to sleep till the next cycle.
- The data collection will take several months.

I thought about the following options:

1. Main program running all time that calls the data collection cycle every hour.
2. Program that just performs a single data collection cycle. Then rely on outsider scheduler to call that program on specific times.

Since the duty cycle of this data collection is very small (setting up the devices and grabbing images sequentially takes less than a minute, compared to about an hour interval), and since it's not healthy for some of the devices to remain active to long periods,  I want to close and reopen the devices' context upon demand.

What option do you suggest to take, for a robust SW?
I'll be happy to consider other options as well :)

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a good use case for the Windows Task Scheduler. It even has an option to wake the computer from sleep to do the work which means the whole OS can be in a low power state most of the time.

Comment: I'd suggest using some well documented software like OpenCV for the job. There are ways to acquire devices and then release them in the library. I do not know if there is some kind of 'wake up' mechanism set up. Maybe the manufacturer of the cameras gives such an interface. Are you dealing with industrial cameras or something like RaspberryPi cameras?

Comment: @meetaig, Thanks for your comments!
I'm dealing with a PTgray camera, FLIR IR camera, as well as with other devices, e.g. USB controller for illumination. I don't think I can rely on all SDKs, at least from memory leaks perspectives, and on top I'm a .NET noob.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Thanks for your comment! As I'm relying on the OS anyhow, it looks like a good path.

Comment: Problem is that the interface of the camera with the computer sometimes does not work without the manufacturer APIs and so on. That's why I asked. I have zero to no experience in C# but some experience in addressing cameras using OpenCV or MATLAB. Getting the computer to talk to the camera is often times half the work in the project. Anyway, for the scheduling of the jobs I would look into the task scheduler as @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three years after, and the solution of @Damien_The_Unbeliever proved itself as a great one! I avoided memory leaks and other drifting sicknesses and was able to run the data acquisition for durations of months.